# How to test a skinny controller without retesting the fat model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, model-view-controller, tdd

Before I start, I'm using rails with rspec, shoulda-matchers, and factorygirl to ease testing, so if those libraries contain something helpful to solve the problem below, please let me know.

I was designing my controller and model, and wasn't sure how to go about testing this situation.

I have a game model, which can contain a bunch of players. Players can only be removed if the game hasn't started yet, so I added a remove_player method to my game model and tested it thoroughly.

In my player controller, I have the delete action calling the remove_player method to actually do the work, and then the action causes a redirect.

How can I make a test that the controller is actually doing what it's supposed to (calling remove_player) without retesting the method? I can test to do a redirect, but that won't fail if in the future, the call to remove_player gets deleted.

I know shoulda-matchers has "should_validate_presence_of" and stuff like that, which is the same idea behind this test, but doesn't work with my own methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried out mocks and stubs last night, and they did exactly what I wanted. [RSpec's mocks](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks) were pretty easy to pick up and are included with the rspec gem.

The basic idea of a stub is a replacement for a real object that you're using to test another object. In the example in my question, I could make a stub of the game model when testing my player controller, and say gamestub.remove_player returns true always. In RSpec you could do that like

```
@game = double("game") #a double is rspec's mock/stub object
@game.stub(:remove_player?).and_return(true)
```

A mock is like a little different in that it is not just a replacement for the object you're mocking, but also a part of your test conditions. You can say not only what your fake object would return if it were called, but that it should be called n times (or the test will fail), and what parameters you expect it to be called with. In the example above, i could mock a game and say gamemock.remove_player should be called once and be passed in the current player and return true (or false if i wanted to test what happened if the test failed). Here's an example kind of like what I did for the players controller.

```
@game = double("game")
Game.should_receive(:find_by_id).with("123").and_return { @game }
@game.should_receive(:remove_player?).with(current_user).and_return(true)
delete :destroy, {:id => 123}
response.should do_whatever
```

Mocks and stubs are pretty similar. [This article](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html) tries to highlight differences. To me it seems it's basically how you use them, since mocks have all of the capability of stubs and can be used as one. That's probably why RSpec treats them as one type (double)